# Location estimation methods based on multiple surfaces

Tags: raster, r

I’m probably reinventing the wheel here and wonder if somebody can point me in a better direction.

I have about 10 surfaces of signal strength (z) received at a transmitter. Here I’ll provide an example with four surfaces `r1`, `r2`, `r3`, `r4`.

```
library(raster)
library(gstat)
set.seed(3178)
n <- 100
r0 <- raster(nrows=n, ncols=n,xmn=1, xmx=n,ymn=1,ymx=n)
r0 <- as(r0,"SpatialGrid")

pts <- data.frame(x=c(10,20,60,80,1,1,n,n),y=c(10,80,70,40,1,n,1,n),
                  id=c(1:4,rep(0,4)), z=c(c(rep(1,4)),rep(0,4)))

pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts[,1:2],data=pts[,3:4])


r1 <- idw(z~1,pts[c(1,5:8),],newdata=r0)
r2 <- idw(z~1,pts[c(2,5:8),],newdata=r0)
r3 <- idw(z~1,pts[c(3,5:8),],newdata=r0)
r4 <- idw(z~1,pts[c(4,5:8),],newdata=r0)

r1 <- raster(r1)
r2 <- raster(r2)
r3 <- raster(r3)
r4 <- raster(r4)
```

I also have a series of points with signal strengths that correspond to each surface. The locations of these points is unknown. The task is to determine a location for each point. E.g., for `unknownXY`:

```
# Extract a point. For the real data I would have the z data but not x and y
cell2get <- floor(runif(1,1,n^2))
unknownXY <- c(extract(brick(r1,r2,r3,r4),cell2get))
```

In this case there is a four-way intersection of the contour lines that I could find suing some kind of intersection technique (e.g., `rgeos::gIntersection`).

```
# Here is the the contour for the unknown point on each raster
plot(r1,axes=F)
contour(r1,levels=unknownXY[1],add=TRUE)

plot(r2,axes=F)
contour(r2,levels=unknownXY[2],add=TRUE)

plot(r3,axes=F)
contour(r3,levels=unknownXY[3],add=TRUE)

plot(r4,axes=F)
contour(r4,levels=unknownXY[4],add=TRUE)

# here are all 4 contours
plot(r0,axes=F,col="white")
contour(r1,levels=unknownXY[1],add=TRUE,drawlabels=FALSE,col="red")
contour(r2,levels=unknownXY[2],add=TRUE,drawlabels=FALSE,col="blue")
contour(r3,levels=unknownXY[3],add=TRUE,drawlabels=FALSE,col="purple")
contour(r4,levels=unknownXY[4],add=TRUE,drawlabels=FALSE,col="green")
```

But there are times when, I think, that there will not be a completely pure intersection (e.g., the contours will not exactly overlap). In that case I’m wondering about using a probabilistic method for finding x,y for a given vector of z.

One thing I was thinking was calculating distances. E.g.,

```
# calc distances
r1d <- sqrt((unknownXY[1] - r1)^2)
r2d <- sqrt((unknownXY[2] - r2)^2)
r3d <- sqrt((unknownXY[3] - r3)^2)
r4d <- sqrt((unknownXY[4] - r4)^2)
plot(brick(r1d,r2d,r3d,r4d))
```

And them summing them:

```
# Straight sum? Should they be weighted in some manner?
rdSum <- sum(brick(r1d,r2d,r3d,r4d))
plot(rdSum)
```

I could find the min value to get the ``best'' point:

```
# Use min to get possible location. Seems easy to get trapped.
rdSumMin <- rdSum == minValue(rdSum)
plot(rdSumMin)
```

Or use a threshold value to get a series of locations that are the most likely:

```
# Or use quantile to get possible locations? 
thresh <- quantile(rdSum, probs = c(0.01))
rdSum99 <- rdSum < thresh
plot(rdSum99)
```

Is there a way of finding a surface that is explicitly probabilistic?

What I’d like to do is be able to determine possible location with x% likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can find a probabilistic answer without an assumption of uncertainty either on your surfaces or your samples.

For example, if you believe that your surfaces are known exactly with zero error and your point sample value is not at a contour intersection then your point sample must have an error in it. You need to specify this error structure, for example you might assume the measured point sample value is from a Normal distribution with mean of the ground truth value and some standard error. That would then translate to a probability surface over each of the surfaces and then (with, I reckon, a few additional assumptions) you could find the location with the highest probability, or draw contours of probability ("this point came from within this contour with p=0.90" or similar).

Conversely if you believe your sample point value is known with zero error and can't be at a contour value then you need an uncertainty model for your surfaces. I've actually implemented this for single surfaces where the surface has a mean and standard error obtained from Kriging: https://gitlab.com/b-rowlingson/revkrig - you could repeat this over your four surfaces and combine the probability surfaces.

The methods you've described look like ad-hoc methods for finding an optimum point but without a probabilistic structure to your data I don't think you can put a probabilistic measure on your answer.

And of course you could have uncertainty in both.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks for making me think through this a bit. I can generate a SE for each surface. I'll investigate.